# Must extract functions in module to use spy/stub/mock with sinon.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Saying I have this file `index.js`:

```
export const f = () => 5;
export const g = () => f();
```

And my `index-spec.js`:

```
import * as F from './index'
const spy = sinon.spy(F, 'f')
F.g()
assert(F.f.calledOnce)
```

This code will not work, but I don't understand the reason. If I extract `f` in another module the code will work.

Can somebody save me! :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not invoking function f.  Change `F.g()` to `F.f()`

Comment: but I want to check that when I call `F.g()`, `F.f()` is called once, it's not possible ?

Comment: This is tricky because it depends on how the es modules are implemented. Sinon works on the assumption of mutable references that allow it to replace values with its created spies that wrap the original function value.  So the question is if the implementation you are using is exposing the original references or not.  I know I have made this work when using require instead of module syntax but I am not sure how it works with modules.

Comment: @Deadron And how did you make it work with require()? Because sinon actually spies on the variable to which you assign the `require(module)` instead of spying on the things exported by the `require(module)`.

Comment: Depends on how you are using it. When you use the stub function and give it a reference to the module it is not possible in javascript to reassign that reference to another value outside of the stub function's scope. In this situation the only thing it can do is mutate the function on the module. If your normal usage is to somehow assign a spy to the reference with a setter then that would be a different use case. However, es module references are I believe immutable so you cannot assign to one. With that said the functions on the module should still be assignable depending on the impl.